# ZipInputStream conversion

Tags: java, php, zipinputstream

i have a java service that take a byte array in order to convert it in one or more pdf files or jpg files. i know this service work because it's called from another java system that correctly send files with no problems. now i need to call this services from a angular js system, the byte array, once reached the java application, it's converted first to a ByteArrayInputStream with not problems then the ByteArrayInputStream it's converted to ZipInputStream but fail. i suspect the problem is the type of encoding of the array.

This is my code:

```
public static Hashtable<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> unzipFile(InputStream inputStream){
    logger.info("Unzip del File");
    Hashtable<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> fileOutputTable = new Hashtable<String, ByteArrayOutputStream>();
    try{
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        ZipEntry zipentry;
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = (ByteArrayInputStream)inputStream;
        ZipInputStream zipinputstream = new ZipInputStream(bis); // here conversion fail
        while((zipentry = zipinputstream.getNextEntry()) != null){
            String entryName = zipentry.getName();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int n = 0;
            while((n = zipinputstream.read(buf, 0, 1024)) > -1)
                baos.write(buf, 0, n);
            baos.close();
            fileOutputTable.put(entryName, baos);
            zipinputstream.closeEntry();
        }
        zipinputstream.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Errore nel tentativo di unzip del file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("RETURN: " + fileOutputTable.toString());
    return fileOutputTable;
}
```

---

```
public static Hashtable<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> unzipFile(InputStream inputStream){
    logger.info("Unzip del File");
    Hashtable<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> fileOutputTable = new Hashtable<String, ByteArrayOutputStream>();
    try{
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        ZipEntry zipentry;
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = (ByteArrayInputStream)inputStream;
        ZipInputStream zipinputstream = new ZipInputStream(bis); // here conversion fail
        while((zipentry = zipinputstream.getNextEntry()) != null){
            String entryName = zipentry.getName();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int n = 0;
            while((n = zipinputstream.read(buf, 0, 1024)) > -1)
                baos.write(buf, 0, n);
            baos.close();
            fileOutputTable.put(entryName, baos);
            zipinputstream.closeEntry();
        }
        zipinputstream.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Errore nel tentativo di unzip del file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    logger.info("RETURN: " + fileOutputTable.toString());
    return fileOutputTable;
}
```

Comment: _..i have a java service that take a byte array..._ Post code...

Comment: What do you mean by "... but fail.". Is there an exception? Then show the full stacktrace and mark the line where it occurs. Did you debug your application?

Comment: it doesn't give exceptions just the ZipInputStream object do not get populated. zipinputstream.getNextEntry() returns null